# Esta operacion con if me da un fallo

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Por que ponga lo que ponga en el prompt el resultado es que mi instrumento es de viento? no encuentro el error.

```js
let musica = prompt("Que instrumento tocas?");

if (musica === "saxofón" || "flauta" || "clarinete" || "trompeta" || "oboe") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de viento`);
} else if (musica === "guitarra" || "arpa" || "violín" || "piano") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de cuerda`);
} else if (musica === "timbal" || "tambor" || "platillos" || "bombo") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de percusion`);
} else if (musica === "bajo electrico" || "guitarra eléctrica" || "theremín" ||
  "sintetizado") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento electrico`);
} else {
  console.log(`${musica} tiene un error vuelvelo a completar`)
}
```

Comment: Esta sintaxis: `musica === "saxofón" ||"flauta" || "clarinete" ||  "trompeta" || "oboe"` no es correcta, en todo caso debe ser: `musica === "algo" || musica === "otro" ........`

Comment: @BetaM es cierto, pero ojala fuese correcta, acortaria bastante las cosas si javascript algun dia la decide implementar, pero por el momento veo que lo mejor que el usuario podria hacer para comparar eso es simplemente clasificando informacion en diferentes array.

Comment: Debe ser una tarea, esta solo haciendo un promtp y comparando valores. Quizás aun no pasan a arrays. @Riven

Comment: Puedes usar arreglos: `if(['saxofón', 'flauta', 'clarinete', 'trompeta', oboe'].includes(musica)) { console.log('es de viento'); }`

Comment: @Triby Como le dije a Riven, puede que sea una tarea, y el nivel requerido es ese, sabemos que se puede mejorar bastante, pero es algo que le han pedido.

Comment: Buena observación, @Excorpion, ya la había leído y por eso solo lo puse como comentario, esperando a ver qué dice OP.

Answer (score 3):

Entre cada '||' debes poner otra vez el comparador

```js
musica = prompt("Que instrumento tocas?");

if (musica == "saxofón" || musica == "flauta" || musica == "clarinete" || musica == "trompeta" || musica == "oboe") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de viento`);
} else if (musica == "guitarra" || musica == "arpa" || musica == "violín" || musica == "piano") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de cuerda`);
} else if (musica == "timbal" || musica == "tambor" || musica == "platillos" || musica == "bombo") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento de percusion`);
} else if (musica == "bajo electrico") {
  console.log(`${musica} es un instrumento electrico`);
} else {
  console.log(`${musica} tiene un error vuelvelo a completar`)
}
```

Comment: Exacto, esta es la respuesta que BetaM sugirio

Comment: Será colocar la comparación de nuevo, pues el comparador solo sería el ===

Comment: Es preferible usar siempre el operador de comparación estricto `===`, aún cuando sepamos de antemano que los valores a comparar son del mismo tipo, esto como un consejo de buena práctica. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear `arrays` independientes por cada tipo de instrumento y comporbar si el `valor` introducido esta en alguna de ellas.

```js
let instrumento = prompt("Que instrumento tocas?");

let instrumentosViento = ["saxofón", "flauta", "clarinete", "trompeta", "oboe"];
if (instrumentosViento.includes(instrumento)) {
  console.log(`${instrumento} es un instrumento de viento`);
}
```

Comment: Y esta es la respuesta que sugerí xd, de todas maneras es valida, pero aun no sabemos si el usuario puede usar `arrays`. o bueno, almenos pensaba hacer exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Esta respuesta me gusta más porque reduce mucho el uso de los operadores de cortocircuito `||`. +1